# Excel VBA Run-time error '91'

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a pivot table with VBA, and I got help from @Shai Rado to be able to create a empty pivot table, and then I added the value field, when I try to run it again, I got an error: Object variable or with block variable not set" for code "With .PivotFields("MedID")"

Which doesn't make sense to me because that part of code already created a empty pivot table and now it shows error.

Any thoughts? I'm totally new to VBA so I have many "silly" questions. I really appreciate any help!!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Pivot_Table()

Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsPT As Worksheet
Dim PT_Cache    As PivotCache
Dim PT          As PivotTable
Dim PRng        As Range
Dim LastRow     As Long

With ThisWorkbook
   Set wsData = .Worksheets("Data")
   Set wsPT = .Worksheets("Pivot Table")
End With

LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox LastRow ' <-- confirm value

Set PRng = wsData.Range("A1:O" & LastRow)

' option 2: Set the Pivot Cache
Set PT_Cache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRng.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True))

' set the Pivot Table
Set PT = PT_Cache.CreatePivotTable(wsPT.Range("D5"), "Pivot_Table_Test")

With PT



   With .PivotFields("MedID")
       .Orientation = xlRowField
       .Position = 1
       .LayoutBlankLine = False
       .Subtotals(1) = False
   End With

   With .PivotFields("TransactionType")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
       .Position = 1
       .LayoutBlankLine = False
       .Subtotals(1) = False

   End With


   With .PivotFields("Quantity")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlCount
        .Position = 1

    End With

Set PT = Nothing
Set PT_Cache = Nothing
Set wsData = Nothing
Set wsPT = Nothing
Exit Sub

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like the object PT is null. Ensure that this line: Set PT =CreatePivotTable(.... is returning a value and setting PT.

Comment: Also try deleting the pivottable as the first line of code(if it exists). I am wondering if the reason its not working is because it already exists.

Comment: @aguertin there's no need to delete the `PivotTable` if it exists, just to check if it is, if it does then all you need is to update it with the updated `PivotCache`, if it's not then Add the `PivotTable`

Comment: @ShaiRado Agreed, but for the sake of knowing what the issue is it is much easier to delete then if that is in fact what is causing the issue, put a condition statement in to check if it already exists and update it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Updated code below (to fit your needs):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Pivot_Table()

Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsPT As Worksheet
Dim PT_Cache    As PivotCache
Dim PT          As PivotTable
Dim PRng        As Range
Dim LastRow     As Long

With ThisWorkbook
   Set wsData = .Worksheets("Data")
   Set wsPT = .Worksheets("Pivot Table")
End With

LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    
Set PRng = wsData.Range("A1:O" & LastRow)

' Set the Pivot Cache
Set PT_Cache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRng.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True))

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PT = wsPT.PivotTables("Pivot_Table_Test") ' check if "Pivot_Table_Test" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PT Is Nothing Then
    ' create a new Pivot Table in "Pivot Table" sheet, start from Cell D5
    Set PT = wsPT.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PT_Cache, TableDestination:=wsPT.Range("D5"), TableName:="Pivot_Table_Test")

Else ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range in "Data" sheet
    PT.ChangePivotCache PT_Cache
    PT.RefreshTable
End If

' === set Pivot Table fields ===
With PT
    With .PivotFields("MedID")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
        .LayoutBlankLine = False
        .Subtotals(1) = False
    End With
    With .PivotFields("TransactionType")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
        .LayoutBlankLine = False
        .Subtotals(1) = False
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Quantity")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlCount
        .Position = 1
    End With
End With

Set PT = Nothing
Set PT_Cache = Nothing
Set wsData = Nothing
Set wsPT = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With this error it looks like PT is not set to PivotTable, so there is nothing to refer like `With .PivotFields("MedID")`. Create PT and the refer PT to your pivottable with name like `Set PT = ThisWorkbook.PivotTables("PivotName")`